# SSD (location of WBM) missing after mobo BIOS update

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, bios, asus

I'm baffled. I'm running an Asus X99-A II with Windows 10 installed on a Samsung 1TB SSD. Today I decided to update the mobo BIOS from v1504 to the (non-BETA) v1902, available on the Asus website here:

https://www.asus.com/uk/supportonly/x99-a%20ii/helpdesk_bios/

I did the update via a USB pen drive and everything seemed to go OK. Until I realised the machine was no longer booting into Windows. With every boot I'm now taken to the BIOS screen, and Windows Boot Manager—which is installed on the Samsung SSD—is no longer visible! Only my 5TB SATA drive is showing.

Here's how things looked just before I updated:

[BIOS showing Windows Boot Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Cgf.jpg)

The Asus BIOS screen is now showing that I've updated to v1902, so I'm assuming that means everything was successful. Any thoughts on what might have gone wrong or what to check?

[BIOS showing update to v1902](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmHXL.jpg)

I know a hardware fault can sometimes be the root cause, but this was working fine seconds before I updated the BIOS. Now this!

I don't think flashing back to 1504 is a good idea, but maybe I should try the BETA v2101 update? Or is there something incredibly obvious I might be overlooking?!

Thanks in advance for any help,

Sk8

Comment: 1. 1902 is described as a BETA bios anyway. 2. why not flash back to working BIOS? 3. try latest non-beta BIOS - 1801, 4. is the *Samsung SSD* a "regular" SATA drive, an M.2 drive or a U.2 drive?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I hadn't noticed 1902 is indeed Beta as well! I also didn't think you could drop back to an earlier BIOS version, but from what you've said, it sounds like that's something I can try so will give that a shot. Also, it's an M.2 drive 

Comment: Good to hear you got it working!  Since (from your answer) you aren't sure exactly why it started working again, I'm voting to close the question since it is "not reproducible" and likely won't be of use to future readers.  That's certainly not a bad thing!  If you do have the problem again, feel free to edit any additional detail in and ask to have it considered for reopening.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, after a few days of not working with the PC and then rebooting, the M.2 drive was picked up by the BIOS and all was well again. Very bizarre!